# Coloring NSMutableAttributedString in UITextView giving weird results

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, nsattributedstring, nsmutableattributedstring

I'm trying to make a rudimentary IDE / code viewer and thus I am trying to color certain words in a `UITextView`. I wrote a small loop to find ranges and another to color the words in range on an `NSMutableAttributedString`. I know the ranges are being calculated correctly because the print statement at the end of the code is giving the correct indexes. However I am observing a very strange result in the app (screenshot below). Any idea what could be going wrong?

**CODE**

```
    var ranges = [[Int]]()
    var rcounter = 0

    for word in content.components(separatedBy: [" ", "\n", "."]) {
        if (word == "func") {
            ranges.append([rcounter,rcounter+word.count])
        }
        rcounter += word.count
    }

    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:content)

    for range in ranges {
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.red, range: NSRange(location:range[0],length:range[1])
    }

    textView.attributedText = attributedString

    print(ranges) // [[0, 4], [288, 292]]
```

**RESULT**

[image: screenshot]

Comment: ` NSRange(location:range[0],length:range[1])`: That's (location,length), not (startlocation;endLocation)

Answer (score 0):

the count of separate char are missing.

check this.

```
        var ranges = [[Int]]()

        var rcounter = 0

        let content = "func asdfasdfasdf. sdfdfdf12323 func adfadfasdf func() func. "
        for word in content.components(separatedBy: [" ", "\n", "."]) {
            if (word == "func") {
                ranges.append([rcounter,word.count])
            }
            //add loop count on every loop time
            rcounter += word.count + 1
        }

        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:content)

        for range in ranges {
            attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.red, range: NSRange(location:range[0],length:range[1]))
        }
```

i hope help for it